# Multiplication in FUN argument

Tags: r, aggregate-functions, multiplication

I have this dataframe

```
x <- data.frame(
        matrix(
          c(letters[1:3], c("x", "x", "y") ,
          sample(c(rep(1,100),0), size = 1),
          sample(c(rep(1,100),0), size = 1),
          sample(c(rep(1,100),0), size = 1)), ncol = 3)
)
```

I would like to do multiplication by group X and Y.

My suggestion

```
agg <- aggregate(x$X3,
                 by = list(x$X2),
                 FUN = *)
```

I would like to use something like `sum`, `mean` byt to multiply

Comment: `*` only multiplies 2 values. You're looking for `FUN = prod` for the *product*.

Comment: While not a factor here, even if `*` were the right function to use here (i.e., two rows each group/data), then you still need to wrap it in backticks, necessary for all infix operators in R. You would need to do `FUN = \`*\`` (though that still won't work for reasons GregorThomas highlighted and fixed in their answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`+` is to `sum` as `*` is to `prod` (for *product*).

Your sample data follows the anti-pattern of `data.frame(matrix())`. A matrix can only have one data type. You mix character and numeric data in the matrix, and the matrix makes it all `character` class, and you can't do math on characters. Here's proper sample data and a demonstration the solution works. Also note that using `by = X["X2"]` instead of `by = list(x$X2)` gives a nicer column name in the result.

```
(x <- data.frame(
          X1 = letters[1:3],
          X2 = c("x", "x", "y") ,
          X3 = 2:4
))
#   X1 X2 X3
# 1  a  x  2
# 2  b  x  3
# 3  c  y  4

aggregate(x$X3, by = x["X2"], FUN = prod)
#   X2 x
# 1  x 6
# 2  y 4
```

Answer (score 3):

Either use prod or use Reduce with *.  Also convert X3 to numeric and and use single brackets as shown to preserve the names.  Alternately use the aggregate formula method, shown only for prod but applies to Reduce as well.

```
xx <- transform(x, X3 = as.numeric(X3))

aggregate(xx["X3"], by = xx["X2"], FUN = prod)

aggregate(xx["X3"], by = xx["X2"], FUN = Reduce, f = `*`) # same

aggregate(X3 ~ X2, xx, FUN = prod)
```

A better example might be to use mtcars that comes with R:

```
aggregate(mtcars["mpg"], by = mtcars["cyl"], FUN = prod)

aggregate(mtcars["mpg"], by = mtcars["cyl"], FUN = Reduce, f = `*`) # same

aggregate(mpg ~ cyl, mtcars, FUN = prod)
```